# Android NSD - Group Owner

Tags: nsd

When creating a network using Android NSD, to enable communication between several devices that have the same application, does one of the devices necessarily becomes the Group Owner, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes one of devices should be Group Owner.
Please use `createGroup(channel, actionListener)` function to become a group owner.